# How do I initialise my form in Django?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I have created a contact form on my homepage but the form does not show until I click on the submit form the first time. I.e. calling the get method. I would like to keep it as a separate view to my homepage so that when re-clicking 'submit' it does not have an impact on my homepage. Is there a way to load my 'def email' when my homepage loads?

template form

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'home_page:email' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
{#            {% bootstrap_form form.as_p %}#}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-default">
        </form>
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^$", views.HomePage.as_view(), name="home"),
    url(r'^email/$', views.email, name='email'),
    url(r'^success/$', views.success, name='success'),
]
```

views

```
class HomePage(MessageMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

def email(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the form in the **HomePage** view context. Like this:

```
class HomePage(MessageMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(HomePage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['form'] = ContactForm(None)
         return context
```